# Ionic 5 problem ng subprocess with angular 14

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this problem. When I compile an application and run the command ionic cordova prepare android i see this error:

```
Error: Unknown argument: platform [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.   ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 1. Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

My Config:
Angular CLI: 14.0.2
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64
If i lunch the same command with this config:
Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64
the project work correctly

Have you a solution??

Answer (score 1):

yo lo logre con este comando ng add @ionic/cordova-builders

Comment: Please note that this is the English only version of stackoverflow. The spanish version can be reached at es.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @JesseZeferino, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange#answer-13684) about that. The intent is in no way to exclude non-English speakers, but rather maintain a "common" language on the main sites without language-specific characteristics (like es.stackoverflow.com I mentioned). In your case, an English question with a Spanish answer will confuse non-Spanish speakers even more (though it is quite short and understandable).

Answer (score 0):

This error happen beacause you don't did the migration of an application in Angular to Ionic, the solution is simple.

Run

```
npm install @ionic/angular@6
```

If you are using Ionic Angular Server, be sure to update that as well:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@6 @ionic/angular-server@6
```

However if that's code don't run try this code:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@latest @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save
```

if need read the documentation of the migration:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration

I hope than help you

Answer (score 0):

try `ng add @ionic/cordova-builders`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of this error was because I had changed my npm version to a different version that wasn't used to install ionic at that time. So, it seems ionic depends on that npm version you used to install it, depending on how drastic the version change was.